# Autoplaylists in Foobar2000: Ways to limit the number of query results

Tags: foobar2000

Using Foobar2000, I wish to create an autoplaylist based on a query and crop the resulting list to a specific number of results.

For example:

- [auto] Playlist of the 50 most played songs
- [auto] Playlist of the las 70 added songs

I have not been able to find a solution to the last part of the query.
There seems not to be a `LIMIT`-operator

I'd love to be able to specify the amount in a number and not limit by adding conditions to the query. Things like:
`%play_count% GREATER 4` or `%added% PRESENT AND %rating% GREATER 3 AND %last_modified% DURING LAST 50 WEEKS`
would limit the autoplaylist but not to a specific length.

It seems strange that there would be no way doing this.

Is there a way to have a counter that does a +1 on every result and maybe limit the list of results that way?

Any pointers are appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you maybe already know it was asked a [couple](http://www.hydrogenaudio.org/forums/index.php?showtopic=90582) of [times](http://www.hydrogenaudio.org/forums/index.php?showtopic=64927) on the FB2K forums.
The best answer I could find is semi-official "No"

> Limiting auto-playlists was mentioned couple of times as I know, but there are still no good news about that

source: [2E7AH](http://www.hydrogenaudio.org/forums/index.php?showtopic=72815&st=0&p=642045&#entry642045), a FB2K validator, Jun 17 2009,

I can assure you nothing has changed since 2009 in this regards. (sadly)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to put together the foobar2k forum links. I had seen the post you cite in your answer but had hopes that something might have changed in the 3.5 years since it was posted... As you well said; sadly it has not. Even though it was not the answer I had hoped for, I'm accepting your answer. Thanks again for your time. Hopefully this will get included in future foobar2000 updates!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure whether this will solve the problem, but such a sort of playlist might be created with the `foo_random_pools` component. It has a limiting option.
This plug-in seems to be tricky to use for the purpose we need, as it has built-in randomization. I needed an autoplaylist limiting to create playlists that contain ¾ never-played tracks and ¼ of my favorite tracks. It seems to be working so far. I do not fully understand how to make the results less random. It has something to do with group, group size and number of groups.